# Setting Nginx to catch all unhandled vhosts

Tags: nginx

If I already have a bunch of virtualhosts, how can I create a virtual host to handle requests that don't match any of the virtualhosts? (i.e. access by IP, another domain linking to IP, .etc .etc)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

server_name _; and default_server on the listen configuration are what you are looking for.

Example:

```
server {

   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;

   root /var/www/default; (or wherever)    

}
```

Comment: And for the https case: `listen 443 ssl default_server;`

Comment: When I enable this, my `owncloud 9` won't respond. Why? Owncloud VHOST has a server_name and is no default_server.

Comment: I don't use `80` only 443 is open.

Comment: If I add this, my other config snippets in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ are ignored. all domains go to `/var/www/default` in this case. How do I have to order the snippets?

Comment: I can create a vhos to postgresql connections?

Comment: If you just want to sinkhole people, you can just do a `return 404` as your last call.

Answer (score 6):

If you use SSL, then you need some extra plumbing for a default_server - certificate and key (that can be self-signed).

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate <path to cert>;
    ssl_certificate_key <path to key>;
    return 404; # or whatever
}
```

Nginx will try to accept SSL connection on an IP/port-matching default_server. If such server is missing cert/key, nginx will drop the connection. It won't try other servers. So don't forget cert/key.

Comment: Important note about the SSL certificate! If the certificate is missing, the whole nginx server will not run (even though `nginx -t` says "ok")

Answer (score 3):

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

  server_name _;
  root /path/to/default;
}
```

The entries are for port 80 (HTTP), port 443 (HTTPS), port 80 IPv6, and port 443 IPv6, respectively.

You could consider adding `log_not_found off;` to avoid adding a log entry for the page not being found.

Answer (score 1):

In the event that you have `listen` directives with explicit IPs listed, you will need to also include these same IPs in your default block's listen directive.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 10.0.0.10:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
}

server {
    listen 10.0.0.10:80;
    server_name foo.example.com;
}
```

Without the `listen 10.0.0.10:80 default_server` directive in the default block, `foo.example.com` would be served for `http://10.0.0.10` even if `10.0.0.10` is your default IP address.