# Another unknown domain added A record of my IP

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain, a-record

I have a domain on GoDaddy and a VPS on DigitalOcean (Ubuntu 14.04 with nginx if that helps). Today I noticed that an unknown domain has added A record pointing to my IP Address on DigitalOcean. All the content of my website is now showing on that domain and all the search engines are showing his domain instead of mine. My domain is `.com` and the other one is `.co.uk`. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Configure your VPS to only serve your site when it's requested via its specific domain name, via a default virtualhost. http://serverfault.com/questions/527156/setting-nginx-to-catch-all-unhandled-vhosts http://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host

Comment: Will that make the search engines add my domain back?

Comment: Out of curiosity: how have you learned that the `.co.uk` domain has added an A record pointing to your server?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/444217/126632

Comment: @ThomasErker I googled a query in which my page was supposed to be, just to check the indexing and I saw that my page was gone and replaced by another unknown domain. I did a whois on this domain and I checked the DNS Records, and I saw an A record pointing to my IP. I suppose he had that IP before me, but for some reason he closed his website without removing DNS records.

Answer (score 1):

Contact the hostmaster / Tech-C / Admin-C of the other domain. It's possible they added your IP by mistake. You get the information with

```
whois some_domain.co.uk
```